# Закрытие пункта меню при открытии другого

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Написал меню на jquery но проблема в том что не закрываются пункты меню при открытии другого по клику , как это реализовать ?Код и разметку прикладываю

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#m1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m1" ).css( "background", "#88B3FF" );
}); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m1" ).css( "background", "#fff" )
}); 
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#m2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m2" ).css( "background", "#88B3FF" );
}); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m2" ).css( "background", "#fff" )
}); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#m3" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m3" ).css( "background", "#88B3FF" );
}); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m3" ).css( "background", "#fff" )
}); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#m4" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m4" ).css( "background", "#88B3FF" );
}); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m4" ).css( "background", "#fff" )
}); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#m5" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m5" ).css( "background", "#88B3FF" );
}); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( "#m5" ).css( "background", "#fff" )
}); 
});
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body{
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
menu,nav{
 display:block;
}
menu,#hide{
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 top:0; left:0;
 z-index:-1;
}
nav{
 width:100vw;
 height:50px;
 background:#fff;
 position:relative;
 top:30vh;
 border-bottom:3px solid #88B3FF;
}
nav:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
nav li{
 float:left;
 display:block;
 width:120px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 list-style:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin:0 1px;
 position:relative;
 left:30px;
}
nav li:hover{
 background:;
}
nav a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#555;
 cursor:pointer;
}
nav ul li div{
 width:99vw;
 position:absolute;
 left:-30px; top:53px;
 display:none;
 background:#88B3FF;
}
nav ul li div:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
nav a:hover{
 color:blue;
}
nav li div ul{
 float:right;
 width:300px;
 background:;
 margin:0 3px 3px 0;
 position:relative;
 left:-5%;top:3px;
}
nav li div ul li{
 width:300px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:-20px;
}
nav li div ul li a{
 color:#fafafa;
}
nav li div ul h3{
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
     <menu> 
  <div id="hide"></div>
  <nav> 
      <ul>
       <li id="m1"><a>Блоги</a>
   <div class="m1">
    <ul>
    <h3>css</h3>
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <h3>html</h3>
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <h3>js</h3>
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <h3>ajax</h3>
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <h3>php</h3>
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </li>
       <li id="m2"><a>Кино</a></li>
       <li id="m3"><a>Форум</a></li>
       <li id="m4"><a>Уроки</a></li>
       <li id="m5"><a>О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </menu>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".m1").hide();
   });
   $("#m1").click(function(){
    $(".m1").show();
   });
  }); 
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема в том что все вкладки можно открыть сразу но они должный закрываться при клике на следующий пункт

Comment: аккордион и меню разные вещи

Comment: Хм, а я подумал, что вам нужно меню по типу аккордеона.

Comment: Вы только не обижайтесь, но в первом приведенном файле обнаружен "индусский код".  Перепишите более универсальным способом, чтобы можно было добавлять и убирать пункты меню только в разметке не изменяя  javascript. Скорее всего ваша проблема сама собой решится. Сейчас сама идея не доработана

Comment: согласен с Тутанхамоном :) (классно звучит :):):) ) @LenovoID у вас в коде прописано пять разных событий в пяти места к одному элементу `$('#hide')`. Пока будете решать эту проблему, решите и все остальные. Кстати, обратите также внимание на то, что этот элемент имеет `z-index: -1;`